# Change the view's path on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I have this class:

```
public abstract class MyController : Controller
{
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
      string viewPath = filterContext/*... .ViewPath*/;
      viewPath = "Some new View Path";
  }
}
```

And I'd like to retrieve and replace the executing view's path by another one. I have tried to debug-view the filter context on a web call, however I did not manage to find a view which is about to render.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting%28v=vs.98%29.aspx):

`Controller.OnActionExecuting Method`: Called **before** the action method is invoked. At this stage, no `ActionResult` exists since the `Action` didn't execute yet.

You better use the `OnResultExecuting` instead:

```
protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;

    if (viewResult != null)
    {
        var razorEngine = viewResult.ViewEngineCollection.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().Single();
        var viewName = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(viewResult.ViewName) ? viewResult.ViewName : filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var razorView = razorEngine.FindView(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, viewName, viewResult.MasterName, false).View as RazorView;
        var currentPath = razorView.ViewPath;
        var newPath = currentPath.Replace("..", "...");
        viewResult.View = new RazorView(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, newPath, razorView.LayoutPath, razorView.RunViewStartPages, razorView.ViewStartFileExtensions);
    }

    base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: The view name is `"Index"` or `""` and never the full view path. How do I get a string like `"~/Views/Controller/ViewName"`?

Comment: I revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: The `viewResult.View` property is always null, even if the viewname is originally correct.

Comment: i am sorry for the question, it is not correct itself. There is no way for MVC to know the exact view path before `OnResultExecuting` method is completed.

Comment: Accepted at least for I found a solution based on your answer.

Comment: I revised my answer again. the approach is a bit risky since it's assuming you're not overriding the default `ViewEngine` and using it to resolve the `ViewPath`. i guess you can apply some more precautions to the code and have it working just fine.

Comment: One more revision. does work for me now, even when no view name specified (`return View()`).

Comment: After replacing the old viewpath with the new path, the url in the address bar remains same. Why ?

Comment: @abcdefghi, are you serious?

Comment: Why would it change the address bar in the client browser?

Comment: I am assuming that the View Path is changed so it should change the route data as well.

Comment: I don't think so. `OnResultExecuting` is taking place way after routing process and my code doesn't change `RouteData`.

Comment: @haim770 : Can you please explain why it should not change the url?

Comment: @abcdefghi because it is the **redirect response** required in order to notify browser about some changes.

Comment: @AgentFire - As you said, it needs Redirect response to nofify browser about changes. Can you please tell what is happening in this context which is updating the View and not updating the url?

Comment: In Asp.net MVC, a request url is being mapped (using registered routes) to `controller`.`action`, the action is then responsible for generating the output (which is `ViewResult` in our case). it doesn't matter what the action decides to return (or what `View` file it loads), it shouldn't affect the url (unless it's explicit `RedirectResult` which will usually cause another http request).